# Cloudfront for nodejs app in EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I want to set Cloudfront for my nodejs app, When i am setting on it i am getting this error
[image]

Comment: Have you configured the node js app on any specific port and have you configured the port with cloudfront

Comment: @Ali Yes,  i am running node app on 8080 port

Comment: Have you opened the 8080 port on the security Group also make sure you have given HTTP Port : 8080 when you setup CloudFront

Comment: @byteC0de - Did you get any solution?